# Задание атрибута name у каждого input по атрибуту id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая форма:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <head>
             <title>FE-Course. Part 3 | Registration form</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
    <body>
     <header class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Registration form</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <form name="registration" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <legend class="col-sm-12">Registration info</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Login" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" placeholder="Confirm Email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Address</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="ZIP Code">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                          <option value="_none">Select State</option>
                          <option value="value1">State 1</option> 
                          <option value="value2">State 2</option>
                          <option value="value3">State 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="Street">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="building" placeholder="Building">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Hobbies</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Music
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Cycling
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Front End
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Girls
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <legend>How did you hear about us?</legend>
                    <select class="form-control" id="about">
                      <option value="_none">Select Please</option>
                      <option value="value1">Google</option> 
                      <option value="value2">Friends</option>
                      <option value="value3">Newspapers</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block" type="submit">Register Profile</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

и необходимо в каждый input добавить атрибут name со значением = id этого элемента c использованием jquery-метода .each

код js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    $("#name").append($(this).attr("id") + "");
});
```

});

Такой вопрос, что не так коде js написал? ибо в консоли он не совсем корректно отображает необходимое. Как я понимаю с задания то в input должен появится аргумент name="c id"

Comment: Данный код вставляет значение атрибута ID всех элементов INPUT типа текст в элемент с ID name. А что нужно?

Comment: что бы в инпуте отображалось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное что-то типо такого:

```
// Берём все элементы нужные нам и ждя каждого
$("input[type=text]").each(function(index, value){
    // Оборачиваем в JQuery
    var element = $(value);
    // И задаем значение атрибута.
    element.attr("name", element.attr("id"))
});
```

Comment: а если type разные в форме, то как поступить?

Comment: а как исключить из этого type=checbox, им не нужно присваивать значения name